# CSS background-image is being displaced by an h2 element

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a set background image using the `background-image` attribute in CSS. Through most of the page it works perfectly. However, when it reaches a certain `<h2>` element, the background image is not shown in the whole area that is defined for the `<h2>`.

How can I fix this?

```css
html {
  background-image: url("https://wallpaperscraft.com/image/city_hong_kong_night_clouds_lights_58330_3840x2160.jpg");
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Dimstone</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Building the website">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>

<body id="b-override">

  <h2 id="header">header</h2>

  <div id="top-navbar">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
      <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">HomePage</a></li>
      <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">SignUp</a></li>
      <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your h2 probably has a background color. Check the styles for that element.

Comment: remove margin from h2 and replace it with padding if necessary

Comment: `h2#header{
 margin-top:0px;
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't the `h2`, but the `body`tag (which has the ID `#b-override`)

Add this CSS:

```
body#b-override {
  background: transparent;
}
```

```css
html {
  background-image: url("https://wallpaperscraft.com/image/city_hong_kong_night_clouds_lights_58330_3840x2160.jpg");
}

body#b-override {
  background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Dimstone</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Building the website">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>

<body id="b-override">

  <h2 id="header">header</h2>

  <div id="top-navbar">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
      <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">HomePage</a></li>
      <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">SignUp</a></li>
      <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Also note: w3.org recommends that "authors specify the background for the BODY element rather than the HTML element." --
 [background @ w3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/colors.html#background)